# inserting multivalue in 1 column

Tags: php

I want to insert into database 2 values, the current selected time then the calculated time. so basically, like this. "7:00AM - 10:00AM" here's what my current codes. it inserts blank into database.

```
$date = new DateTime($res_dur);
$date->add(new DateInterval('PT3H'));
$date->format('H:i:s');
$ndate = $_POST[$res_dur][$date];

$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_reservation(
            res_no,cust_id,pack_type,plan_id,res_date,res_dur,
            res_venue,pack_choice,date_app,add_ons,res_comm) 
        VALUES
        ('','{$cust_id}','{$pack_type}','{$plan_id}','{$res_date}','{$ndate}',
            '{$res_venue}','{$pack_choice}',CURDATE(),'','')";

$result_set = mysql_query($query);


if ($result_set) {
    echo "<script language=javascript>alert('You have been successfully registered!')</script>";
    header("Location:home.php");
```

Comment: What is the type of the field you are trying to insert that value into?

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: @UlrichSchmidt-Goertz i'm inserting it into varchar

Comment: Why aren't you using two columns ? It will be much simplier to read, calculate, insert and update...

Comment: And you have made sure that the variable you are passing contains the correct string?

Answer (score 0):

Add some debug code to find out where the problem is.

```
$date = new DateTime($res_dur);
$date->add(new DateInterval('PT3H'));
$date->format('H:i:s');
$ndate = $_POST[$res_dur][$date];

print_r( $_POST );
echo '<br>ndate = ' . $ndate . '<br>';

$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_reservation(
            res_no,cust_id,pack_type,plan_id,res_date,res_dur,
            res_venue,pack_choice,date_app,add_ons,res_comm) 
        VALUES
        ('','{$cust_id}','{$pack_type}','{$plan_id}','{$res_date}','{$ndate}',
            '{$res_venue}','{$pack_choice}',CURDATE(),'','')";

echo 'query = ' . $query . '<br>';


$result_set = mysql_query($query);


if ($result_set) {
    echo "<script language=javascript>alert('You have been successfully registered!')</script>";
    header("Location:home.php"); 
} else {
    echo 'Query failed - ' . mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error() . '<br>';
}
```